# Invalid x86 movq instruction

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to figure out why this instruction is invalid but I just can't wrap my head around it.

```
movq (%rax, %rcx, 3), %rbx
```

Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How about you start by explaining why you think it is valid.  What do you expect that this is supposed to do?  Generally, the platform and specific assembler would be useful to know also.

Comment: It moves Mem[%rax + 3 * %rcx] to %rbx. I just realized that the reason why it's invalid is because the scale is invalid. You can only multiply %rcx by 1, 2, 4, or 8. Thanks!